# Google Service Location API needs internet?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am learning the Google Maps API V2 and now I am reading about the `Location API`, the documents says it connects a `client` to the `Service`:

> Location Services sends the current location to your app through a
>   location client, which is an instance of the Location Services class
>   LocationClient. All requests for location information go through this
>   client.

Does this means that Google will be getting all the positions where my app is? I know Google Maps can work in offline mode if the maps are already downloaded, but does the Location services only function online?

I need to control the internet traffic in my app, so hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it works:

### Way 1: Cell Tower Triangulation.(Using Mobile Data)

This way uses your service providers Network connection to figure out where you are. The Longitude and Latitude returned are most definitely not the most accurate however, they get you to with 10-15% accuracy (in my experience).

Here is a snippet of code that illustrates this (pulled directly of the Android website)

```
// Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

// Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
      makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
  };

// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

### Way 2: Wifi Connection. Have to be online.

This method is much more accurate than the previous one. However the drawback is that you have to be online and connected to the internet. This method uses the same theory as your JavaScript version of Google maps found on any web browser. The Longitude and Latitude returned by this method are almost exact.

### Way 3: GPS. (Offline)

GPS is most accurate, it only works outdoors, it quickly consumes battery power, and doesn't return the location as quickly as users want. However GPS requires no connection to the internet or Mobile data. It gets your location via a request to public satellites.

Here are the two functions you need. [getLatitude() and getLongitude().](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getLatitude%28%29)

Keep in mind this is all fun and stuff. But the google maps api v2 has a simple [function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/location)

`mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)`;

which considers all three possibilities t get your location.

Comment: Yes, but `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)` is just to show in the map the current location, not to use it for code right? To use it in code I need the Location API.

Comment: You are correct. To get the latitude, longitude for yourself you must use the location services api.For everything else that is cool(like a human readable address) you must use the gecoder services and pass it the latitute , longitude parameters.

Comment: But in a nutshell...does it require internet access? I know how it works to define the location, and I know GPS doesn't need internet, but I don't know if the API always need to use some sort of connection with google to give back a result.

Comment: No. Gps alone can do it